# Saving data to to devices calendar

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using query mobile, and phonegap to create an app. Within the app I am building a basic list which holds dates and associated information. I want the user to be able to click the list item and for the data to be saved to their own calendar.

I have searched online, and can't seem to find anything relating. Can anyone help push me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap does not expose an API to access the device calendar.But I think you can create a phone gap plugin for this purpose.I am not sure about the feasibility of this.May be this [link](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36752779/PhoneGap%20Plugins) will give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Android Calendar access plugin for PhoneGap : https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/CalendarPlugin